# Why does TableToTable give ERROR 000732 when published to ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, arctoolbox, error-000732

I have a python code that uses ArcPy command "arcpy.TableToTable_conversion" to convert a database table to a dbf file.

```
arcpy.TableToTable_conversion
```

The input table is from a SQL Server database through an odc Database Connection in ArcCatalog.

```
"Database Connections\\myDb_DEV.odc\\dbo.V_Locations"
```

When run straight from ArcCatalog, the code worked perfectly. However, after it was published as a Geoprocessing service on ArcGIS Server 10, it failed to run.

```
Error
Error Executing Task. Error executing tool.: : Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000732: Input Rows: Dataset "Database Connections\myDb_DEV.odc\dbo.V_Locations" does not exist or is not supported Failed to execute (TableToTable). Failed to execute (ExportToBOMAWS).

Code: 500
```

Could anybody help with any idea why and how to make it work as geoprocessing service?

Comment: I have been struggling for days. Please help out.

Comment: I don't have access to ArcGIS Server to test but I think you need to make sure that Catalog on your server machine is seeing the table identically to how Catalog on your desktop machine sees it.  Right click on the properties of that table using Catalog on both machines and see if the full path and sde connection parameters are absolutely identical.

Comment: right, the table to table conversion works, but only creates an empty table... i'm just stuped here.

Answer (score 2):

When authoring a Python script that will be later published as a GP service, you have to specify the .sde / .odc connection file (you have to copy it from C:\Users\%user%\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcCatalog) as your workspace (copy it from . Then use `os.path.join` to reference a database object such as a table. When you use "Database Connections", it is not something your script would recognize since you don't run from ArcMap or ArcCatalog session.

```
import arcpy, os
oleworkspace = r"C:\GIS\ole.odc"
gdbworkspace = r"C:\GIS\Temp\test.gdb"
indata = os.path.join(oleworkspace,"dbo.V_Locations")
outputdata = "V_Locations_output"
arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(indata,gdbworkspace,outputdata)
```

[What happens when you publish a geoprocessing service](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00570000004t000000)

Answer (score 1):

If myDb_DEV.odc is the server name, then I have seen the same error and the reason for it is because I did not add .sde extension behind my server name.

Check your servername by looking at the server properties->Editor Tracking.

The Realm: @ text field is usually the name you should use.